# SQL Database restore to different edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I have SQL server 2008 R2 standard in house server and want to move my database to SQL 2019 Web edition in VM in AWS cloud. Can I just backup database and restore it there? would that work? or standard edition can only be restored to standard not web edition? Database is not that big, under 30GB.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Database Migration Assistant (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/prepare-for-upgrade-by-running-data-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver15). It should identify any issues you're going to see. In addition, there are different hardware limitations between standard and web editions. Read all about that at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore older versions of SQL Server databases to newer versions. This is how a lot of people upgrade their instances - build a new one and transfer the databases over.

The supported SQL upgrade paths for SQL Server 2019 are here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#migrate-to-sql-server-2019 --  note even though SQL Server 2008 R2 is not explicitly listed, it is mentioned that you can do a backup/restore to a 2019 instance.

Comment: Thank you Mark, yes I saw that link and it does say we can migrate sql 2008 r2 to sql 2019 by manual backup and restore, the confusion I have is between the editions? from standard Edition to Web edition because web edition is only available in clouds and lot cheaper than standard edition. So will that work too? or my destination sql must be standard too?

Comment: The database will certainly be portable, different SQL editions are often just additional features and hardware licensing. The core database is the same in all editions (exception of Express which has a size limitation)

Comment: Ok thank you Mark, I'm gonna try and let's see how it goes. Appreciate it.